# Performance of DWORD vs QWORD alignment in 32 bit code

Tags: c++, memory, c++builder, memory-alignment, borland-c++

I have a lot of objects that inherit from each other etc.

Default Embarcadero C++ Builder 2009 has set Data alignment in properties to QWORD.
If I change this to DWORD many of my objects shrink in size, because often they have 4 bytes to spare and again in an inheriting object etc.  So accumulated this has a good effect.

Shrinking them is appealing since sometimes I need to allocate millions of them in memory.

I would like to know why QWORD is the default for a 32 bit application ?  I expected it to be DWORD in fact. And will changing it to DWORD create performance issues ?

Also, since I allocate lots of them in memory, are they allocated nicely packed together, one after the other, or is there padding between them as well, and is this padding also based on the project setting (Data Alignment: QWORD / DWORD) ?   If the objects are all allocated on QWORD boundaries changing the actual objects' sizes won't have a net effect.

Comment: If your objects are *actually* changing then you should not be changing that setting.  Since that means you are mis-aligning 64-bit variables.  Like *double*, very expensive.  About x2 slower if misaligned by 4, over x3 slower if misaligned across a cacheline.

Comment: Your data structures are probably changing sizes due to padding between members. I suggest you review your data structure layouts and try to reduce padding between members.  One way is to group all variables of the same type together, rather than intermixing.  Another suggestion is to place the largest types first (such as 64-bit pointers or integers).

Comment: Do you allocate your objects using a single malloc() (i.e., in an array), or does each get its own malloc? In the latter case, there will be at least 8 bytes between objects for the metadata that the memory allocator uses.

Comment: How are you measuring alignment?  If you are looking at sizeof(), I can't think of any advantage, other than perhaps some exotic cache advantages.  If you're looking at memory utilization, malloc allocates in blocks of 8 bytes beause it is type-unaware when allocating, so you would see a lot of waste.

Comment: @Sjlver Every object is created with new and its pointer is added to an array.

Comment: @Cort Simply trying to find a way to reduce the total size of memory allocated in case I need to 'remember' a lot of objects (a file system with lots of files for instance)

Comment: @Hans I do use 64bit variables.  I hadn't considered that downside.

Comment: @Thomas  I already organized the members to reduce lost space between them, but since I often have 4 bytes to spare 'at the end of an object' and since this may be the case for several objects that inherit from each other, the accumulated loss is higher than 4.  The DWORD setting fixes this.

Comment: I suggest you consider shrinking the size of the variables.  For example, if your integer never goes past 65536, you may want to consider using a 16-bit integer rather than a 32-bit or 64-bit.  This may be worthwhile when you have a lot of objects.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I do already but thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Overall, there are a number of things to consider for alignment:

First, according to [the Wikipedia page on Data Structure Alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment), Embarcadero might be a bit of an exception if it aligns all objects to 8-byte boundaries. The article claims that GCC, VC++ and Borland's computer don't align data at 8 bytes unless it's a `double` or `long long`.

A number of things do force alignment:

- `malloc` and `operator new` will give you memory regions that are 8-byte aligned. Also, if you perform separate calls to `malloc` or `new`, the objects won't be nicely packed together. There will be at least 8 or so bytes between them for allocator metadata. There is also no guarantee that the objects are close to each other in memory.
- Stack frames are aligned to 8 or 16 bytes, depending on the architecture
- SSE instructions need 16-byte aligned data

Regarding performance: I don't think you'll see a large difference between 4-byte and 8-byte alignment. [Daniel Lemire measured](http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2012/05/31/data-alignment-for-speed-myth-or-reality/), and found small, if any, differences between 1-byte and 4-byte aligned data; I expect them to be even smaller between 4 and 8 bytes.

Probably the biggest performance and memory usage difference in your scenario could come from allocating space for many objects at the same time (e.g., by storing them in a `std::vector`) instead of calling `new` for each individual object.